# (api) .htaccess rewriting for /backend and /frontend folders

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, nuxt.js

I'm trying to host a nuxt + symfony project, and I'm kind of stuck here.
I suppose what I need is some .htaccess rewriting.

I have 2 separate folders :

```
/
- /backend, which is basically my symfony folder.
- /frontend, containing my nuxt app.
```

I would need to redirect all of the requests that do **not** contain `"/api"` to the `/frontend` folder, and all requests containing `"/api"` to `"/backend/"`.

Example :

`mydomain.com/articles/5` would redirect to `mydomain.com/frontend/articles/5`
`mydomain.com/api/article/5` would redirect to `mydomain.com/backend/article/5`

Any help would be really useful,
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have additional `.htaccess` files in the `/frontend` and `/backend` subdirectories that also use mod_rewrite to route the URL then you could do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "/api/<something>` to backend
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) backend/$1 [L]

# Everything else rewritten to frontend
RewriteRule (.*) frontend/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, however I seem to be getting the following error : 
`Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: As I say, this does assume you have additional `.htaccess` files in the `/frontend` and `/backend` subdirectories used to route these URLs - this would prevent the internal rewrite loop. I guess this is not the case? How are these URLs routed? What other directives do you have? And what other `.htaccess` files do you have in subdirectories? Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: It certainly would make sense to monitor the http server's error log file. That way you find out what is the actual cause for that http status 500. That should make it easier to find a fix.